# MariaDB Spider with Galera Clusters failover solutions

Tags: mariadb, sharding, failover, galera, maxscale

I am having problems trying to build a database solution for the experiment to ensure HA and performance(sharding).

Now, I have a spider node and two galera clusters (3 nodes in each cluster), as shown in the figure below, and this configuration works well in general cases.:

[image]

However, as far as I know, when the spider engine performs sharding, it must assign primary IP to distribute SQL statements to two nodes in different Galera clusters.

So my first question here is:

Q1): When the machine .12 shuts down due to destruction, how can I make .13 or .14(one of them) automatically replace .12?

- The servers that spider engine know

[image]

Q2): Are there any open source tools (or technologies) that can help me deal with this situation? If so, please explain how it works. (Maybe MaxScale? But I never knew what it is and what it can do.)

Q3): The motivation for this experiment is as follows. An automated factory has many machines, and each machine generates some data that must be recorded during the production process (maybe hundreds or thousands of data per second) to observe the operation of the machine and make the quality of each batch of products the best.
So my question is: how about this architecture (Figure 1)? or please provides your suggestions.

Comment: (unrelated)  If all 6 servers are in the same building, HA is a problem with floods, earthquakes, etc.

Comment: @RickJames The clusters will be deployed on the cloud in the future.

Comment: You might check out the HA capabilities of the Cloud; it may be 'as good as' Galera.

Comment: "Thousands" of inserts per second may require "sharding".  This is another topic.

Comment: Sharding is needed in my case, but I don't know how to switch Spider's primary server from .12 to .13 or .14 in Galera Cluster 1. Could you help me address this please? @RickJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MaxScale in front of the Galera cluster to make the individual nodes appear like a combined cluster. This way Spider will be able to seamlessly access the shard even if one of the nodes fails. You can take a look at [the MaxScale tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-setting-up-mariadb-maxscale/) for instructions on how to configure it for a Galera cluster.

Something like this should work:

[image]

This of course has the same limitation that a single database node has: if the MaxScale server goes down, you'll have to switch to a different MaxScale for that cluster. The benefit of using MaxScale is that it is in some sense stateless which means it can be started and stopped almost instantly. A  network load balancer (e.g. ELB) can already provide some form of protection from this problem.